Git Push Fails Due to RPC Errors and Slow Transfer Speeds During Large Repository Push
I encountered issues while pushing a large repository, where the operation failed due to RPC errors and slow transfer speeds. I attempted to resolve this by increasing the http.postBuffer size in the Git configuration, but the push still failed, likely due to network instability or server-side limitations.Despite these efforts, the issue persists, requiring further investigation.
Is there any procedure or solution for resolving this issue?
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
git config --global https.postBuffer 1048576000

Also tried these configs in git but nothing worked for me.

What do the RPC errors say? Do you push to GitHub? If so, I believe GitHub does require Git Large File Storage to be enabled to save files above a size of 100MB. If I'm not mistaken you are increasing the postBuffer variable to a size of 1000MB. Also maybe try using ssh to push instead of http.
